# LINQ Query Field<T> Dynamic?

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic, field

Is there a solution to make the field in a LINQ Query dynamic ?

For example :

```
var query = table.AsEnumerable()
.OrderBy( x => x.Field<string>(myValue)).CopyToDataTable();
```

There is a way to make `Field<Type>` Dynamic ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a generic method. Something like:

```
public void QueryOrderBy<T>(T myValue)
{
    var query = table.AsEnumerable()
                     .OrderBy(x => x.Field<T>(myValue))
                     .CopyToDataTable();
}
```

Comment: I don't understand very well this syntax ... Maybe more explanation please

Comment: Ok I think I just found a solution and also I'm understanding this syntax !! Thank you